# In .htaccess to prioritize DirectoryIndex to a RewriteRule

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want files to be accessed when they are available as specified in the DirectoryIndex line. E.g. when someone types in www.mywebsite.com/mydir/ it will redirect correctly. For this I have in my .htaccess the line:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html default.php
```

When a filename or directory does not exist I want it to redirect to a file (target_handler.php) which is located in the same directory as my .htaccess file. For this I have placed several lines after the DirectoryIndex:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{ENV:URI} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [ENV=URI:$1]

RewriteCond %{ENV:BASE} ^$
RewriteCond %{ENV:URI}::%{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)::(.*?)\1$
RewriteRule ^ - [ENV=BASE:%2]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}target_handler.php [L,QSA]
```

What I want is for Apache to first check to see if there is an index.html or default.php available, and only upon unavailability perform a rewrite. Currently the behaviour seems random(?), so if someone types www.mywebsite.com/mydir/ then Apache sometimes does the rewrite first without checking if there is an index.html in the specified folder.

Help appreciated

PS: I am testing using: xampp
Apache/2.4.17 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2d PHP/5.6.15

Comment: This won't work because `DirectoryIndex` is not part of `mod_rewrite` it uses `mod_dir`, you can't have it check then if not use your rewrite rules. Apache doesn't work that way. DirectoryIndex does what it's supposed to. You need to use rewrite conditions to check the existence of those files.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. In what way can I apply such conditions in order to be able to check for an index.html or default.php?

Comment: @user2022678: Is this .htaccess in site root or in a sub directory?

Comment: @anubhava .htaccess is in a subdirectory; basically my setup is /webroot/website1, /webroot/website2 etc.. each subdir has it's own .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

You can omit `DirectoryIndex` and do it all using `mod_rewrite` itself:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(.*?/)(.*)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [E=BASE:%1]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{ENV:BASE}index\.html -f
RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{ENV:BASE}default\.php -f
RewriteRule ^ default.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule !^target_handler\.php$ target_handler.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. It now however seems to be caught up in an infinite loop (the url bar tries to access files in a loop)

Comment: It will loop only if `target_handler.php` also doesn't exist along with default handlers. Check updated answer now.